# Assuming only static members initialized, does implicit default constructor remain trivial?

Tags: c++, static-members, default-constructor

Based on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), if there is no non-static members initializers then the default constructor is considered trivial, so does this mean if we add a static member, default constructor still remains trivial and the class type is POD? In other words, if in a C compatible class type we declare and initialize a static member, can we still consider the struct a POD type? For example,

```
struct PodType {
    static int n = 10;
    float x;
    float y;
};
```

Is the above struct C-compatible (POD)?

Comment: Yes, this class is trivially constructible, and standard layout. Plain reading of cppreference, as well as Standard, points to this conclusion.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks. can you explain why the class is still "trivially constructible" and what do you mean by "standard layout"?

Comment: [Standard Layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Standard_layout)

Comment: `Standard layout` is how we call `POD` classes nowadays. It is trivially constructible because it fits all requirements for trivially constructible classes, mentioned in Standard 11.2 (latest draft)

Comment: I couldn't find a good description of Trivially Constructible that didn't look like it was written in Martian. [Link to Section of the Standard Sergey is talking about](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.prop). And yes, that link is what I mean by "Looks like it was written in Martian." Read slowly and carefully and follow the links to other sections, which you then read slowly and carefully, and you can figure it out.

Comment: @Omid -- You have [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) that would answer your question, such as `std::is_trivially_copyable`, `std::is_pod`, etc.  to tell you about the types.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie nice it's really handy

Comment: @user4581301 thanks for the info. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the helpful comments, I can safely say the struct still remains trivial (aka POD) after adding the static member.
Furthermore, [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) provides various convenient helpers to check characteristics of a type, such as `is_trivial`. Similarly, there are compilers specific support for type traits, for example with [Microsoft C++ compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/compiler-support-for-type-traits-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-160) we can use `__is_pod`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo {
    static constexpr int n = 10;
    float x;
    float y;
};

int main () {
    // msvc compiler-specific type trait:
    __is_pod(Foo) == true ? printf("true\n") : printf("false\n");

    // <type_traits> header type trait:
    std::is_trivial<Foo>::value ? printf("true\n") : printf("false\n");

    return (0);
}
```